# Count how many devices are exceeding capacity per site

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office, pivot-table

I'm currently trying to get a list to show how many 'devices' are exceeding capacity, basically look at a cell, recognise the site name, look across to `exceeded capacity?` cell, see if = Yes then +1 to the count for that site?

I have done a Pivot table to count how many = 'yes' but because the value is a string it does not allow me to filter 'greater than'..

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You might try renaming the "K:K" sheet to something shorter and ensuring the two arrays are of the same size. So maybe:

```
=COUNTIFS(SitesExceedingCapacity!A:A,"Alderaan",DEC_July!K:K,"Yes")
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you need the total to be, just use this formula:

```
=COUNTIF(D:D, "yes")
```

***Note***: This assumes your yes/no output is in column D. Adjust the range as necessary.

Edit: From the comments; you can use `Countifs()` to check multiple criteria. You would create one for each site.

Example, we will use `site1` for your first site:

```
=COUNTIFS(D:D, "site1",K:K, "yes")
```

This will check columnD to match the site name, then column K to check if it's `yes`.

Comment: I need it to show it individually per site, for example:

Column A - Column B
Site 1 - 30
Site 2 - 15

Comment: @JackBrownridge Why do you have multiple columns for the site?

Comment: Sorry, that didn't format correctly, I have the site names in column `D` & Exceeded capacity colum in `K`

Comment: So the "yes/no" text is in column `K`?

Comment: I've done `=COUNTIFS(SitesExceedingCapacity!A2:A111,"Alderaan",'Devices Exceeding Capacity_July'!K:K,"Yes")` & this shows `#VALUE!` ??

Comment: Just to add, I've created a new sheet with only the site names then the amount, this makes it less cluttered.

Comment: @JackBrownridge I wasn’t aware that you had this information on separate sheets. I believe countifs will only work if all criteria is on the same sheet (you can reference from a different sheet, but the criteria has to be on same sheet)

Comment: @pnuts I should have tested this then before I provide assumptions because that is news to me :D --- I am not limited on the length of my sheet tab however (by the amount OP shows that is)

Comment: @pnuts the 31-char limit also applies to me. OP's second sheet is exactly 31 chars

Comment: @pnuts maybe a difference between 64/32 bit architecture?